# How to store a 0.2 value in sqlite3 database using python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to store a percentage value as a decimal in a sqlite3 database by dividing the user input by 100.

However, within the database, the value stored is always 0 if the column type is INTEGER or 0.0 if the type is REAL.

I've tried changing the datatype.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO recipes (rname, customer_id, bar_weight, ingredient_id, ingredient_amount) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?/100)"""
```

Expected: 20/100 = 0.2

Actual: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of this statement:

```
select 20 / 100
```

is `0` because SQLite does integer division.
To avoid it use `100.0` instead:

```
INSERT INTO recipes (rname, customer_id, bar_weight, ingredient_id, ingredient_amount)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?/100.0)
```